# Ring homomorphism from $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ into $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

I was working on this problem

> Find all ring homomorphisms from $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt:-
I found that if we have any ring homomorphism $\phi$, then $\ker(\phi)$ should be either zero or the entire ring (since $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ is simple) and in case the ideal is the entire ring the ring homomorphism should be zero mapping. But I am  not sure if we have case where $\ker(\phi)={0}$.

Comment: Is $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ the algebra of $3\times3$ real matrices?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli its matrix algebra or matrix ring.

Comment: It makes a big difference whether it's an algebra or a ring. If you work with rings, then $\ker \phi$ can never be $0$ (use the fundamental isomorphism theorem), so your question is quite easy in this setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no injective ring homomorphism $\phi:M_3(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$ for simple reasons: consider the matrix $A=\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0}$. Notice that $A^3=0$. Then $\phi(A)^3=0$, so $\phi(A)=0$. Since $\phi$ is injective we get $A=0$, false.

Answer (score 3):

A ring homomorphism from any matrix ring containing $\mathbb R I$ to $\mathbb R$ is also an algebra homomorphism:

1. If $\phi$ is not identically $0$, $\phi(I) = 1$ because $\phi(x) = \phi(I x) = \phi(I) \phi(x)$.
2. If $n \in \mathbb Z$, we then get $\phi(nI) = n \phi(I) = n$.
3. If $r$ is rational, $\phi(rI) = rI$.
4. If $0 \le c \in \mathbb R$, then $\phi(cI) = \phi((\sqrt{c}I)^2) = \phi(\sqrt{c}I)^2 \ge 0$.
5. If $c \in \mathbb R$, take sequences of rationals $a_n, b_n \to c$ with $a_n \le c \le b_n$.  Then $a_n = \phi(a_n I) \le \phi(c I) \le \phi(b_n I) = b)n$, from which we conclude $\phi(cI) = c$.
6. Thus $\phi(c x) = \phi(cI) \phi(x) = c \phi(x)$, i.e. $\phi$ is an algebra homomorphism.

In particular it is a linear mapping over $\mathbb R$.

Since $\dim M_3(\mathbb R) > \dim \mathbb R$ (as vector spaces over $\mathbb R$), it's impossible for the kernel to be $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no injective ring homomorphism since every matrix of the form $AB-BA$ must be mapped into $0$. To conclude, it is well known that there exist some $AB-BA \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It is known that every injective ring homomorphism $\phi:M_n(K)\rightarrow M_m(K)$ must satisfy $n\le m$, see for example Lemma $3.2$ [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0509188.pdf). For $m=1$ and $n=3$ this is a contradiction. One could also use the Amitsur-Levitzki theorem.

Comment: Your answer make me wonder: Did we have $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homormphism $\phi:M_n(K)\rightarrow M_m(K)$ other than zero mapping ? and thanks for that reference its really useful.

Comment: thanks,can you give me any reference to this or did this have any name.

Comment: You mean, a name other than Lemma $3.2$ ? I don't know any name except for the [Amitsur-Levitzki theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amitsur%E2%80%93Levitzki_theorem) in this context.